# Why is には used in this sentence instead of は?

Tags: grammar

*It hasn't been answered. Please help.*

> なぜ殺されたのか君**には**わからないのですか?

Please help me understand why they use [には] in this sentence. Compare with [は], what is the difference it makes in that context ?

I have taken a look at [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39304/rules-for-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF-usage) that may be a duplicate, but however it does not help me resolve my question. That question seems to compare に with には while I am comparing は with には. I would like to find out the difference if は had been used in my example sentence instead.

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of ["Rules for には usage"](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39304/).  This question asks about は or には with 分かる.  The specific verb is very important here, as each verb licenses its own specific arguments, and 分かる licenses both dative and nominative subjects, each of which behaves differently with topicalization.  The linked answer doesn't really cover any of this, and we should only close a question when the existing answers answer a new question well.  (That's the purpose of closing as duplicate, to help people find answers.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of に in 「私には本物の若殿様がわかります」](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/24955/use-of-%e3%81%ab-in-%e7%a7%81%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af%e6%9c%ac%e7%89%a9%e3%81%ae%e8%8b%a5%e6%ae%bf%e6%a7%98%e3%81%8c%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99)

Comment: This one is also related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36481/5010

Comment: Since this was marked as a duplicate of the "Rules for には usage" question, we've reopened it and closed it as a duplicate of a question with a more closely related answer.  Narutokage, please also take a look at the other question naruto has linked to.  I think that one might help you as well.

Comment: It's pretty hard to choose between the answers because the accepted answer didn't satisfy me much, so I think that it's better to wait for others which are not likely going to appear in the older question. But it's OK by now, I already had the answer myself.

Comment: This question repeats because learners are not taught that the agent of わかる is originally marked with に and the usage with が is derivative.

Answer (score 2):

は is just a normal topic marker.
は  just gives emphasis to 君に

The whole problem is the に

君に分かる is slightly different to 君は分かる。

君は分かる = you understand
君に分かる = a person like you understands

So the sentence becomes:
君にはわからないのですか?
A person like you can't understand this?

It implies that everybody else understands, but you are the only person who doesn't understand.

So the whole sentence becomes something like:
なぜ殺されたのか君にはわからないのですか?
How come you don't know why this person was murdered? (when everybody else does).