# What is the particle には doing in this sentence?

Tags: translation, particles

What does the bolded には mean in the following sentence?

> 貫くような衝撃が顎から脳天を突き抜け、次第に目の前が真っ白になってゆく感覚に襲われる中、耳**には**銀髪の外国人の興奮した声が入ってきていた。

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rules for には usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39304/rules-for-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af-usage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a particle に (marking a direction/destination) followed by a topic/contrast marker は. は is used because there is a weak contrast between what's happening to his 目の前 and what's happening to his 耳.

> **耳には**銀髪の外国人の興奮した声が入ってきていた。
>   (literally) **into my ears**, an excited voice of a foreigner with silver hair was coming.